# Apache Beam TextIO glob get original filename

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, clob, apache-beam

I have setup a pipeline. I have to parse hundreds of *.gz files. Therefore glob works quite good.

But I need the original name of the currently processed file, because i want to name the result files as the original files.

Can anyone help me here?

Here is my code.

```
@Default.String(LOGS_PATH + "*.gz")
String getInputFile();
void setInputFile(String value);


    TextIO.Read read = TextIO.read().withCompressionType(TextIO.CompressionType.GZIP).from(options.getInputFile());
        read.getName();

        p.apply("ReadLines", read).apply(new CountWords())
         .apply(MapElements.via(new FormatAsTextFn()))
         .apply("WriteCounts", TextIO.write().to(WordCountOptions.LOGS_PATH + "_" + options.getOutput()));

    p.run().waitUntilFinish();
```

Answer (score 5):

This is possible starting with Beam 2.2 using a combination of `FileIO.match()`, `FileIO.read()` and custom code to read lines of text. You can already use this at HEAD, or you can wait until release 2.2 is finalized (it's currently in progress).

```
PCollection<KV<String, String>> filesAndLines = 
  p.apply(FileIO.match().filepattern(...))
   .apply(FileIO.read())
   .apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<ReadableFile, KV<String, String>>() {
     @ProcessElement
     public void process(ProcessContext c) {
       ReadableFile f = c.element();
       String filename = f.getMetadata().resourceId().toString();
       String line;
       try (BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(Channels.newInputStream(f.open()))) {
         while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
           c.output(KV.of(filename, line));
         }
       }
     }
   }));
```

Comment: would you happen to know if there is an easy way to solve my problem here for python now? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53404579/dataflow-apache-beam-how-to-access-current-filename-when-passing-in-pattern

Comment: Using your solution, the final output is a key-value pair. In order to write the actual line (value) to the appropriate file (key), would I need a custom sink? Or is there a better way to specify what needs to be written?